# Django nested regroup

Tags: python, django, templates

I use Django 2.2.12

I have three models: RiskRating is pointing to RiskType which is pointing to RiskCategory with ForeignKeys.

```
class RiskCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)

class RiskType(models.Model):
    riskcategory = models.ForeignKey(RiskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="risksforcategory")

class RiskRating(models.Model):
    risktype = models.ForeignKey(RiskType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratingsforrisk")
```

In my view:

```
riskratings = Riskrating.objects.all()
```

I would like to display RiskRating grouped by RiskCategories, i.e. I would like to do a nested regroup as following:

```
{% regroup riskratings by risktype.riskcategory as ratingsbycategory %}
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Nesting groupings is easily done by first doing the main grouping and within the for loop of that do the sub-groupings.

Comment: I understand, but I don't need to group by RiskType. Only directly by RiskCategory.

Comment: Maybe you can just pass the list of all the categories, and then in your for-loop (in your template), you display all their grand-children (ratings) ?

Comment: Thanks @Benbb96. But I need to filter on childrens and grand-childrens

Comment: I can't say I'm certain if that's possible with Django templates straight away (I prefer Jinja2, much more flexible) but if it's not possible there is an easy workaround. Create a function like this on `RiskRating`: `def get_riskcategory(self): return self.risktype.riskcategory`. After that you can do `{% regroup ... by get_riskcategory ... %}`

Comment: Alternatively you can also sort by the category and use `{% resetcycle riskrating.risktype.riskcategory %}` to fake grouping.

Comment: What you are doing seems to work according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#grouping-on-other-properties), Edit: the objects do need to be sorted by the riskcategory first though.

Comment: @Wolph use comments to ask clarification or suggest improvements, please post your answer in the `Answers` section.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat : In the documentation you mention, "description" is a field of country, not a ForeignKey

Comment: @PaulNoon a foreignKey is also a field so it should work, if it doesn't work you can try `risktype.riskcategory_id` to use its id.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat : You are right, thank you very much. I don't know why it did not work initially.